# Attribute editing in QGIS on geoJson file

Tags: qgis-plugins, geojson

We have vector files in the format of geoJson files. We need to keep it in geoJson format as it is picked up by mobile devices via Restful services.

The problem is we want to change the attributes of the features in QGIS but it seems like this is not possible. We don't have to add or remove columns. We simply need to edit the existing data.

Is there a work around for this?

Are there any plugins that I can download that will allow me to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QGIS uses OGR/GDAL library to read and write different formats. So this issue is about OGR/GDAL. You can check here [link](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html). It can read and write in geojson but can not update. So you must convert geojson to another format like shapefile, by the way you can edit data. After editing you convert your data to geojson format. This means three step **"convert-edit-convert"** Not only geojson files but also GML, KML, MDB files arent edited directly...

Answer (score 2):

Quick update, this question, and answer are not relevant anymore. You can now edit geojson in QGIS.

Comment: no you can't ... see my question here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319450/qgis-values-in-attribute-table-become-null-after-saving?noredirect=1#comment520276_319450

Comment: I would not say "no you can't", but I would say you have encountered a bug. Because it supposed to be working in QGIS, to be able to edit GeoJSON. I just tried now with 3.6.2, I could edit an existing geojson in the attribute table (modifying an existing field).

Comment: Just tried with QGIS 3.28.2.  I couldn't edit the GeoJSON, but the saving to shape file, editing shape file, and re-exporting to GeoJSON worked.

Comment: Maybe it's like CSV, there are two ways to open a CSV file : one is editable, the other one not. Maybe it's the same with GeoJSON. How do you open it ? I both two ways, from the browser or from "add vector layer", it both works for me.