# latest version of QGIS fails to edit attribute table of GeoJSON file

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.6.4 and working with GeoJSON files. I have come across a very annoying problem. Whenever I try to add an attribute and assign values to it using the field calculator, the values will appear to update and the field looks correctly populated. However as soon as I exit out of the attribute table (while saving changes) and reopen it the entire column is converted to NULL.

I have tried playing around with the precision and width of the output field to no avail. I don't think this is related to coordinate system units since this is not a geometric operation of type `$area` or `$length`. It is more like A*col1+B*col2.

Has anyone had such an issue before? Please help... I would have thought basic functionality like this is already well tested and bug free in QGIS....

**EDIT**

Other symptoms include:

- new field disappears if I remove the layer and add it again from file location, despite having saved layer changes....
- a separate geojson file called result.geojson.tmp is created and contains the modified attribute table. However my result.geojson is unchanged. Adding an attribute field and populating it should not create a new file but modify the current one in place... why does this happen?
- I have also attempted this with QGIS 3.6.1 - Same problem.

The problem appears to be under discussion in the [QGIS issue tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760)

Comment: U have this behavior each time u change the structure of a table ? ...

Comment: no, adding and deleting fields seems to work fine... I just can't edit the contents....

Comment: And u **never** succeeded in editing the content when u were doing this ???

Comment: I would succeed before, but unpredictably so... Now it is systematically failing even after closing and reopening the whole program.

Comment: Is it specifically related to **GeoJSON** format ?

Comment: So ... my question was : do your problems appear only when playing with geojson ?

Comment: it seems to work OK with shapefiles...

Comment: GeoJSON seems to be a weird format regarding this in general. Had issues manipulating attribute tables in QGIS, ArcGIS and ArcGIS Pro. Now I convert the format, edit attributes and then convert it back if needed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't waste your time like I did. This is a [QGIS bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760#change-97363). I spent several days trying to solve this issue.

There is no solution at the moment.

I posted the same issue on QGIS bug report. I don't know what developers 
did, but after version 3.2.3, GeoJSON files doesn't work on windows OS (it creates a temp file on the same location and all the edits only apply on temp file).

My suggestion is to downgrade to 3.2.3, I did this in our company and it works well.

Comment: It seems to work with QGIS 3.2.3. How lame that newer versions of the software actually break vital functionality! The developers should really look into this...

Comment: the developers seem to be unable to reproduce it on their machines - if you follow the bug you can see what is happening. If you company is dependant on this functionality you can contribute sponsorship to get it fixed.

Comment: They did reproduce the issue. the reason why they were unable to reproduce it at the beginning is, they were trying on Linux while this is Windows problem, not Linux.