# Loading a GeoJSON in QGIS using Python but the layer can't be edited

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geojson

```
def loadLayer(self):
    layer = self.dlg.listWidget.currentItem().text()
    url = self.getRoute(layer)
    data_req = requests.get(url)
    data_layer = data_req.json()
    with open('xx.geojson','w+') as f:
        json.dump(data_layer,f)
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('xx.geojson',layer,' ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

I'm getting data from a server in the form of a feature collection.  I write it into a GeoJSON file then load it in QGIS. The layer loads properly but if I try to edit some features it is not possible.

Comment: Not possible in QGIS? or are you trying to write back to the original source?  What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Different possibilities:

- You are using a QGIS version that does not allow GeoJSON edit (was readable only in the old times e.g end of https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13797 as it's related to GDAL version)
- Known issue on Windows (unresolved at the moment) also mentioned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319451/638 (reference issue https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760)

Did you also try something like `iface.activeLayer().isEditable()`? Sometimes not editable due to file permissions.